# startService and registerReceiver after crash other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a problem with my application. By default, the start `MainActivity` that runs consecutively `Activity` A and B. If B has an error, it means the application is interrupted, the execution of my program returns to `Activity` A cycle of behavior - `onCreate`, `onStart`, and `onResume`. Everything would be fine but does not work logging. Ie. if I go back without error to the `Activity` of A or it is created the first time everything works properly. The problem is when the B error.

This is my code (fragment of onCreate):

```
    gV = new globalVar().getInstance();        

    startService(new Intent(A.this, TaskMsg.class));        
    startService(new Intent(A.this, GPSLoggerService.class));

    up_orderlist = new UpdateOrderList();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(UPDATE);
    registerReceiver(up_orderlist, filter);
```

I emphasize - the first call or return to the A, everything works properly. The activity responds to the received signals.

How to do everything returned to normal after running onCreate when an error occurs in another activity?

Comment: Crash how? Please post the logcat.

Comment: **"How to do everything returned to normal after running onCreate when an error occurs in another activity?"** - Just fix the code in the other activity so it doesn't crash.

Comment: Create a handler that catches the exception uncaught exception and restart your application.

Comment: I deliberately cause an error to see how the application behaves. Ultimately, there is no error, however, I want to solve all the possibilities because the case went to this problem and can not solve it.